# Python SQLalchemy TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

> *this question is not a duplicate of another question and I have already tried the answer given in that question and it did not solve
>   my problem. Thanks.

I'm a beginner in Python and learning how to use SQLalchemy.

1. I am trying to retrieve all rows from my database table
2. returning the results as a list of objects
3. my js code will read the list of objects and display into view

However I have been getting this list object is not callable error. Can someone give me a guide on this please thank you.

```
@mod_core.route('/getDatatable', methods=['GET'])
def datatable_get():
    # Query 'user' table.
    _user = User.query.all()
    _results = []
    for user in _user:
        print user.get_all()
        _results.append(user.get_all())
    return _results
```

> 127.0.0.1 - - [22/Jan/2017 17:10:46] "GET /getDatatable HTTP/1.1" 500 -
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2000, in **call**
>       return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1991, in wsgi_app
>       response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_restful/**init**.py", line 271, in error_router
>       return original_handler(e)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1567, in handle_exception
>       reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1988, in wsgi_app
>       response = self.full_dispatch_request()
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1642, in full_dispatch_request
>       response = self.make_response(rv)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1746, in make_response
>       rv = self.response_class.force_type(rv, request.environ)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 847, in force_type
>       response = BaseResponse(*_run_wsgi_app(response, environ))
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 57, in _run_wsgi_app
>       return _run_wsgi_app(*args)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 871, in run_wsgi_app
>       app_rv = app(environ, start_response)
>
> TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

**UPDATE 1 : I have also tried changing User to Json before returning and still gets the same error:**

```
@mod_core.route('/getDatatable', methods=['GET'])
def datatable_get():
    # Query 'user' table.
    _user = User.query.all()
    results = []
    for user in _user:
        results.append(user.to_json())
        print results
    return results
```

**User class**

```
   def to_json(self):
      """
      Return a JSON response for RESTful API GET request.
      """
      _user_in_josn = {'login_id': self.login_id,
                       'fullname': self.fullname,
                       'nickname': self.nickname,
                       'matric': self.matric_no,
                       'email': self.email,
                       'alt_email': self.alt_email
            }
      return _user_in_josn
```

**UPDATE 2 : Tried to cast to JSON before returning results**

> User object at 0x7f88f80b14d0> is not JSON serializable

PLease guide me along. Thank you for your kind attention and help.

Comment: a stack trace would help

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly where your problem is coming from, but I do see a confusing thing you're doing with your `user` objects.  You've obtained a `user` in your loop, but you're still calling `user.get_all()`.  I'm not sure what that is supposed to do because, at that point, `user` is just one user object.  Do you want the `user`'s database ID?  Some other piece of data like the username?

Try changing that line to something like this:

```
_results.append(user.id)
```

That will add the `user`'s ID to your list.  Or you could append whatever other data you have stored in your `user` object.  If you want to `return` a full list of all users in your database, then do this:

```
return _user
```

I might also suggest renaming those variables `_user` and `_results`.  Using the leading underscore is usually just for hidden variables, and there doesn't seem to be any need for that here.  Also, since `_user` stores many `user` objects, a name like `users` would probably be more appropriate to indicate what the variable contains.

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply! I want to return a full list of all users in my database. I tried return _user, but it gives me this error TypeError: 'list' object is not callable.

Comment: It could be coming from how you use the list that your function is returning.  Look at that part of your code and see how you use the data you return.  It's just a list, so you can loop over it, or you can index it with square brackets like this `users[0]` but you can't call it like a function (which would look like this `users()`).

Comment: thanks for your reply! i used angularJS to ask flask for the data. $http.get("/getDatatable").then(function(response){ $scope.tableresults = response.data }....

Comment: i didn really call it like a function here. merely just bind the results into the angular $scope. Can I learn which part needs to change please?

Comment: I see that the question was marked as a duplicate.  Looking at the answer for that other question, I think it will solve your issue here.  The problem is returning the list object directly, instead of returning that list as a part of a response object.  Check out that other question for more details, and it should help you better than I have.

Comment: Hi I have no idea why my question is duplicate as I already tried the solution given in the other question and its not working. Casting results to jsonify gives me ERROR:User object at 0x7f88f80b14d0> is not JSON serializable. Can you help me please, I have no idea what is wrong with this.

Comment: You could try something like this: `jsonify([u.serialize for u in users])`.